# Use fields from query inside labels

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have a database of employees and I would like to generate contracts for them. I am using the report tool to do so, but I need to include their information inside labels. The information is inside the database, but I don't know how to reference it from the labels. Thank you!

I tried doing it like this:

```
= [EmployeeName] & " text included in the contract " & [EmployeeAddress] & " more text from the contract"
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible, help me please.

Comment: Use a text box, not a label. There (or in the record source query) you can use expressions like the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a report you can change the Record Source property to a Table/Query name. In this table or query you can have the information you want to use and you can use it just like you mentioned, =[EmployeeName] if that is the name of the field in your Table/Query

Look at the image below, its from one of my Reports in Access. As you can see, I am using a Table under the Record Source, in this table I have fields name "LastName", "ABS", etc. I am also using a TextBox from an Form too. You can use a lot of stuff as long as  you do it properly.

[image: Report Sample]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't set the Record Source, that was the problem :)